# TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object . Can anyone help me to solve the error in face-recognition

Tags: python, video-capture, face-recognition, opencv

I'm trying facerecognition project, I tried the code and there is one error which i'm unable to solve so I kindly request anyone to help me....

```
File "C:\Users\kmanj\PycharmProjects\faceregonition\main.py", line 48, in <module>
    _, frame = video_capture.read()
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object
```

I'm getting this error. Please help me

**This is my code:**

```
import cv2
import os

cascPath = os.path.dirname(cv2.__file__) + "/data/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml"
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier()
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture()
while True:
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    _, frames = video_capture.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frames, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(
        gray,
        scaleFactor=1.1,
        minNeighbors=5,
        minSize=(30, 30)
    )
    # Draw a rectangle around the faces
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(frames , (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('Video', frames)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
        video_capture.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**This is the error I'm getting**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kmanj\PycharmProjects\faceregonition\main.py", line 48, in <module>
    _, frame = video_capture.read()
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object
```

Comment: try passing the argument to `videoCapture` function, here have a look : https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dd/d43/tutorial_py_video_display.html

Comment: What happens if you do `cv2.VideoCapture(0)`? Also you should check something like `video_capture.isOpened()` and throw an exception if that is `False` it may give you more pointers.

Comment: Perhaps it is because you define a variable `cascPath` but never actually used it?

Comment: `VideoCapture.read()` should **always** have returned a tuple of two things. this error should never ever happen. something isn't right here.

Comment: You are missing argument. should be  face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(face_cascade)

Comment: yeah that too. lots of issues in this code. that's secondary though, didn't cause this error.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kmanj\PycharmProjects\faceregonition\myfacecode.py", line 6, in <module>
    video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
TypeError: VideoCapture() takes no arguments                                                                                                 THIS IS THE ERROR I'M GETTING WHEN I PUT ARGUMENT

Comment: `TypeError: VideoCapture() takes no arguments`? that error should **not be possible**. it always allows an argument. what is going on here? what did you install? some version of OpenCV from 5-10 years ago?

Comment: potentially pycharm messed something up. the only traces of this exact error I can find have involved pycharm in some way.

Comment: I had recently installed OpenCV it's not old, I tried this code in another laptop there also I'm getting same error and it has been more than 15days stuck in same problem so please someone help me @ChristophRackwitz

Comment: *precisely* show how you install the opencv-python package. `pip list` and share the output. you can [edit] your question to amend it.

Comment: C:\Users\kmanj>pip install opencv-python
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: opencv-python in c:\users\kmanj\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (4.5.5.64)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.14.5 in c:\users\kmanj\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from opencv-python) (1.22.3)                                                                                
@ChristophRackwitz

Comment: [tour], [ask], [mre] -- problem is not reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used this API before, but according to the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#a57c0e81e83e60f36c83027dc2a188e80), it looks like you specify the video source in the cv2.VideoCapture() constructor.

Leaving the constructor blank and then calling .read() is returning None (as there is no video to read frames from), and None cannot be unpacked into two variables, hence the error.

This is some speculation on my part. Maybe someone with more experience with this API can clarify.